# How to passed a std:string into a 2D array using std::vector in c++?

Tags: c++

I want to store the content of .txt file in a 2D array.
I am a beginner in c++ and I don't know how to do that.

So, currently, I can read from a file and display it content. Moreover, I can store in a buffer (std::string)

This is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    std::ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(argv[1]);
    if(!inFile) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } else { 
        std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(inFile)),
              std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        std::cout << str;
        inFile.close();
}
    return 0;
}
```

My .txt file looks like that

```
cat file.txt

----------
|        |
|        |
|        |
|        |
----------
```

So, can you help to find the best way to store my file in a 2D array ?
Do you know what is the best way to do that ?

Thank you for answers

Comment: Do you want each word in your lines to be tokenized? Why do you exactly want to store them in a 2D array? If not (as i see from file.txt), you can think of each string in your vector as the second dimension, since you can reach each character in it.

Answer (score 3):

So you want a `vector` of `char`s that is 2D, correct? That, expanded, is a `vector` of `vector`s of `char`s

My approach would be this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(argv[1]);
    if (!inFile) {
        std::cout << "Unable to open file: " << argv[1] << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    
    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::vector<char>>lines;

    while (std::getline(inFile, line)) { //while there still are lines in inFile, put one into line

        std::vector<char> chars;

        for (int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) {
            chars.push_back(line[i]); //put every char of line into chars
        }
        lines.push_back(chars); //put the vector of chars into the vector of vectors of chars
    }

    //when you reach here, you have a vector of vectors of chars

    char curr = lines[1][1]; //You can access a member like this.

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
```

This is simpler than using `streambuf`s and `streambuf_iterator`s, I think.